# Tracking button clicks on Magento with Mixpanel

Tags: php, javascript, html, magento, mixpanel

I'm trying to track clicks on **Add to cart** button on Magento with Mixpanel. I'm following instructions from [the mixpanel blog](http://blog.mixpanel.com/2012/10/08/link-tracking-in-mixpanel/).

My tracking code looks like this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        mixpanel.track_links("#button btn-cart", "Clicked Add to Cart");
  </script>
```

Where **button btn-cart** is the css selector for the add to cart button. I've put this code inside the `addtocart.phtml` file. But no event is being tracked on Mixpanel. Could I get some help with this?

Answer (score 1):

The "#" sign is used for ID values, not for classes. In the addtocart.phtml file's case, the button in question has no id by default, but instead the two classes of "button" and "btn-cart". Because "button" is a relatively generic class used for most (or all buttons) in Magento, we'd want to target the "btn-cart" class by using a "." before the it (versus the # sign).

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   mixpanel.track_links(".btn-cart", "Clicked Add to Cart");
</script>
```

Of course there's probably better ways to do this than littering your .phtml files with Mixpanel calls, but that's a whole other project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that selector is correct.  If you post your theme's HTML we'll know for sure, but base/default is

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" id="map-popup-button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

So you would need

```
mixpanel.track_links("button.btn-cart", "Clicked Add to Cart");
```